# How to improve regex to find best suitable URL string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a few URL strings and I want to get only the one which has not query parameter.

These are my strings:

```
1. https://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/mip/mr-ks-407372
2. https://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/mip/mr-ks-407372?lid=1001117669298
3. https://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/mip/mr-ks-407372?geo_location_terms=&lid=1001117669298&search_terms=
4. https://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/mip/mr-ks-407372?lid=1001117669298/map_locations?chain_id=101130&radius=4.2
```

Now, I want to match only the first string but not the others. I am using this `regex` : `re.search(r'mip/\w+?.+\d+[^/]$', url)` to find the match and I am able to eliminate string no. 3 and 4. But still, I am not able to eliminate string no. 2 and get string no.1. Using this above mentioned `regex`, I am getting string no.1 and no.2 as a match. But I want string no.1 only.

Are there any ways to improve this regex to find string no.1 which has no extra query parameters?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `mip/(?:[^/]+/)*\w+-\w+-\d+$` https://regex101.com/r/tCY7nW/1

Comment: Use `mip/[^\d/?]*\d[^/?]*$` or `mip/\w[^\d/?]*\d[^/?]*$`

Comment: Note that if you do not want to make sure the value is at the end of the string, you may remove `$` in the regex above. And if you do not need to check for a word char at the start and a digit somewhere inside, you may go without a regex, see  answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
mip\/[^?]+$
```

Details:
`[^?]+` matches any character until it meets a `?`.
`$` end of match.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xnSUNg/1)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I choose your answer over others because your answer was simple and more effective. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

No need for regex, just drop urls with a `?`.

```
[u for u in urls in not '?' in u]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urlparse`

**Ex:**

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse     #python2 --> import urlparse

data = ["https://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/mip/mr-ks-407372", 
        "https://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/mip/mr-ks-407372?lid=1001117669298", 
        "https://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/mip/mr-ks-407372?geo_location_terms=&lid=1001117669298&search_terms=", 
        "https://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/mip/mr-ks-407372?lid=1001117669298/map_locations?chain_id=101130&radius=4.2"
        ]

#python2 --> result = filter(lambda x: True if not urlparse.urlparse(x).query else False, data)
result = list(filter(lambda x: True if not urlparse(x).query else False, data))
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['https://www.yellowpages.com/new-york-ny/mip/mr-ks-407372']
```